# Get data from a table and store into variable using groovy?

Tags: groovy

i have a table named person with column name as lst_name, fst_name and id.
Using groovy how can i get all data from the table and store into variable?

Table person:
lst_name,fst_name,id
Jean, Lafontaine,123

my groovy code store only last_name
groovy query:

```
 StringBuilder last_name = new StringBuilder()
    def person_lst_name = sql.eachRow("select * from person where id = "123"") { row -> 
    last_name.append( "Last Name: ${row.lst_name}" )
    }
    //Set properties
    String lst_name = last_name.toString()
   testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "last_name", lst_name )
```

How can i get all value: lst_name, fst_name into variables?

Answer (score 1):

```
def person_id = 123
def person = sql.firstRow("select * from person where id = ${person_id}")

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "last_name", person.lst_name )
```

Comment: Thank you i know to get lst_name but do you get lst_name and fst_name in the same time ?

Comment: @psLaVerriere `"${X}"` is just `X` -- or if you are paranoid `X?.toString()`. I don't see how `def`-ing something inside an `each` will be the "solution".  If you have figured your problem out yourself and this helped you but is not solving your problem it's perfectly fine on SO to create your own answer.